# Using urllib.request to write an image

Tags: python, urllib2

I am trying to use this code to download an image from the given URL

```
import urllib.request

resource = urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1184/1013364004_bcf87ed140.jpg")
output = open("file01.jpg","wb")
output.write(resource)
output.close()
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-43fe4522fb3b> in <module>()
     41 resource = urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1184/1013364004_bcf87ed140.jpg")
     42 output = open("file01.jpg","wb")
---> 43 output.write(resource)
     44 output.close()

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'
```

I get that its the wrong data type for the `.write()` object but I don't know how to feed `resource` into `output`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, Using `urllib.request.urlretrieve` like this way:

```
import urllib.request

resource, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve("http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1184/1013364004_bcf87ed140.jpg")
image_data = open(resource, "rb").read()
with open("file01.jpg", "wb") as f:
    f.write(image_data)
```

PS: `urllib.request.urlretrieve` return a tuple, the first element is the location of temp file, you could try to get the bytes of temp file, and save it to a new file.

[In Official document:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#legacy-interface)

> The following functions and classes are ported from the Python 2 module urllib (as opposed to urllib2). They might become deprecated at some point in the future.

---

So I would recommend you to use `urllib.request.urlopen`,try code below:

```
import urllib.request

resource = urllib.request.urlopen("http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1184/1013364004_bcf87ed140.jpg")
output = open("file01.jpg", "wb")
output.write(resource.read())
output.close()
```

Comment: Does it download to my current directory? Because I don't see it..

Comment: @oo92 Sure, `"file01.jpg"` is the path of the image you download.It should located at current working folder.